# Drummer is called 3 hours earlier on day 1 band rehearsals in Whiplash

Tags: plot-explanation, whiplash

Why does Terence Fletcher (JK Simmons) call Andrew (Miles Teller) 3 hours early on the first day of rehearsal in the band?

In the movie they show Andrew rushing to the rehearsal room thinking he is late, only to wait after reaching there for about an hour before everyone else comes in.

This incident is not explained later on, but it has enough weightage in the movie to make one wonder what it was about.

Comment: Because the character of Terence was a huge asshole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it was 3 hours. Fletcher asked Neiman to come in at 6am when rehearsal only started at 9am.

Personally I believed that Fletcher was:

- Making a statement
- Testing Andrew's will and determination
- Wanted to see how passionate Andrew was
- Wanted to have some fun with the newbie

Comment: I like how Fletcher asks him over to tell him 6am. He knew that if he told him out loud that someone might of said something :)

Answer (score 10):

It's not one hour, it's **three hours**. Andrew was asked to come at 6:00 AM but everyone assembled and teaching started at 9:00 AM.

Since you've seen the movie you must have already understood what Fletcher's character is like.

**He pushes people beyond what's expected of them and he believes it is an absolute necessity.**

When Andrew arrives shortly after 6:00 AM, he is surprised to see the classroom is empty and discovers that the class starts at 9:00 AM. It must be Fletcher's way of telling Andrew to get familiarized with the place and it is Fletcher's band and he would push a student to any extent to win the competition.

Comment: Sure its 3 hours? :) I will make correction in my question then.

Comment: @Man yes I'm sure it's 3 hours.